# python manage window order for game

Tags: python, tkinter, window-management

I'm curious about how to retrieve specific windows and change their order in Python. Can you provide some guidance?

I attempted to use PyGetWindows to retrieve specific windows in a game and create orders based on a GUI where I entered numbers for the order, but I encountered difficulties.

here is my code which recovers the current windows but I don't know how to manage the order of the windows

```
import pygetwindow as gw
import tkinter as tk

def get_dofus_window_names():
    open_windows = gw.getAllTitles()
    dofus_window_names = []

    for title in open_windows:
        index = title.find(" - Dofus")
        if index != -1:
            dofus_name = title[:index]
            dofus_window_names.append(dofus_name)

    return sorted(dofus_window_names)  # Trie les noms par ordre alphabétique

def update_labels():
    dofus_names = get_dofus_window_names()
    label_text.set("\n".join(dofus_names))

# Crée une fenêtre tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=300, height=100)
root.resizable(False, False)

# Crée un label pour afficher les noms de fenêtres
label_text = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

# Crée un bouton pour mettre à jour les noms de fenêtres
update_button = tk.Button(root, text="Mettre à jour", command=update_labels)
update_button.pack()

# Affiche les noms de fenêtres triés au démarrage
update_labels()

# Lance la boucle principale de l'interface graphique
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.